# Copy Data from webpage chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selection

I was trying to copy some data from a webpage and I was using

```
window.getSelection().toString();
```

Works fine in most cases, but if there is a frame or a fancy site or trying copy from google hangout(inside gmail), it won't copy that what selected and I tried with document.getSelection also but no luck. Any one know any other way we can copy data from a webpage ?. My full code is this

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'var dataToSend;dataToSend= window.getSelection().toString(); ' +'chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: dataToSend });'});
```

Any help much appreciated.

**Update**
Added some minimal code to re create the issue
    background.js

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab) 
{
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      code: 'var dataToSend;dataToSend=\"\";dataToSend= window.getSelection().toString(); ' +
          'chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: dataToSend });'
  });
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    if (msg.text !== undefined) {
      alert(msg.text);
      }
  });
}

var title = "My Menu";
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":["selection"],"onclick": genericOnClick});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name"                   : "Test Copy",
  "version"                : "0.1",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "permissions"            : [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background"             : {
    "scripts"    : ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts"        : [{
    "matches"    : ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js"         : ["background.js"],
    "run_at"     : "document_end",
    "all_frames" : true
  }]
}
```

It works in most site it won't work sites with frames like http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.tabs.query({
      "active": true,
      "currentWindow": true    
      }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
          "functiontoInvoke": "getSelectedDataFromPage"
        });
      });
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    if (msg.selText !== undefined && msg.selText != "") {
      copyToNext(msg.selText);
      }
  });
```

From my background script to I send my content_script and inside my content script window.getSelection works because we can add all_frame true which will works every where.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [document](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/04/chrome-43-beta-web-midi-and-upgrading.html), from Chrome 43 onwards, developers can now programmatically trigger to copy and cut actions using *'document.execCommand('copy')'* and *'document.execComand('cut')'* anytime.

Your app/extension has to declare the clipboardWrite: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions

You can call *'document.execCommand('copy')'* after you have manipulated the '*window.selection'* to point to the data you want to copy.

Here is a link for a complete guide on how to do it: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands

**Note**: Copying is a security limitation of every browser. It is a security hole if any website is allowed to take data.